# Are there more Battle Sprites?

Tags: spiral-knights

Are there more battle sprites to discover/buy? I've searched around but all I've found are posts saying something like, "There are currently three starter sprites to choose from, (list)". I'm not sure if this means they are the only ones or they are just the only starter ones. So are the three starter Pokem- err Battle sprites, the only ones to choose from, or are there more to find?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently there are only 3: Drakon, Maskeraith, and Seraphynx. These are collectively called "The Starter Sprites" because the devs have said that more sprites are planned (but not yet implemented).